# What information will be made public by CRT and for how long?

Tags: privacy, evidence, small-claims-court, british-columbia

I would like to bring a case to the Civil Resolution Tribunal. I would like to know more about it's privacy. From there [Information Access & Privacy Policy](https://civilresolutionbc.ca/resources/information-access-privacy-policy/#will-the-crt-share-my-information-with-the-public) it appears the public can access just about anything at any time. How exactly does one get the information, is there a link that leads to a website of the archives?

From what I've red, evidence should be submitted in its totality. The defendant used group chat a lot, so there would be several people talking about completely unrelated (and sometimes rather personal - like who's turn it is to fix the toilet backing up). Will all this be made public? By e-mail I asked a mutual friend to try to moderate. He did facilitate an agreement which the defendant didn't honor. Will this person's email address be made public too?

Will all this show up in a simple Google search of a person's name?

Answer (score 1):

The link that you give is explicit about the information that is made public. Specifically, the decisions of the CRT are publicly posted and if they adjudicate the dispute then all evidence is public and available, presumably on request so it’s unlikely to show up in a search.

This is a continuation of a long legal tradition that the government’s execution of justice must happen in public, partly because, in common law countries, court decisions set precedent but mostly to prevent government abuse.

Their site says:

> What if I don’t want information about my dispute made available to the public?
>
> If a party or witness is concerned that information in a final decision or order would be harmful to their privacy or security, they may request that this information be redacted or anonymized.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116125/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-what-information-will-be-made-public-by-crt-and-f).